# CakePHP 3.2 - Generating XMLview from local XML file

Tags: xml, file, cakephp

i programmed all the time with CakePHP 2.5.
Now I switched to 3.2 and have a problem which i don´t get solved.

The goal is an dynamic XML file which is needed for a videoplayer

In version 2.5, i could do this in the controller with following lines

```
    public function genxml($id = null) {    
            if (!$this->Video->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid video'));
    }

    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml'); 
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Video.' . $this->Video->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('video', $this->Video->find('first', $options));
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work in version. 3
Here I have used following lines, but I did not lead to the result which I achieved.

```
    public function genxml($id = null) { 
            $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
            $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'xml');

            $video = $this->Videos->get($id);
            $this->set('video', $video);
            $this->set('_serialize', ['video']);
    }
```

What should I do to certain values ​​in a pre-XML file query is then generated as an XML file?

Thank you for your help before starting.

Jerome

Answer (score 0):

Did you add routing file extensions to your routes.php?

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
 $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
 // Other code
}
```

This allows you to dynamically generate JSON and XML file like a `/cakeapp/articles.xml` (If you want `/cakeapp/articles/index.xml` is the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::extensions('xml');
```

Remove this line from your routes.php file.

```
$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
```

Add this line after `Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {` in your routes.php file.

Now, just put `/AppFolder/YourController/genxml.xml`. This should return data from your method. (This line doing it `$this->set('_serialize', ['video']);` )

Comment: Please [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38507876/edit) if you want to add additional information. Do not post multiple answers.

Comment: I did what you said. works well so far.previously had exactly the same result with my line "Router::extensions('xml');"
now i get an xml output but which I can not use because it does not have the certain rules for the video player.
Therefore my question, how can I use a pre-xml file. in cake2 that was no problem. but currently I fail cake3.